# Aligning side-by-side nested divs in BS4

Tags: bootstrap-4, alignment

I'm trying to align two div's horizontally. The left div can have any number of items while the right will just have one. This is for Bootstrap 4 so I used the nested example for that version but it doesn't work for some reason. The example does say the nested col's should have a size but since that number can vary I can't do that.  Here is my [[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/w4hasvky/7/)][1](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/w4hasvky/7/). Here's my example code. Would someone please take a look and explain the problem?

**         .box {border:1px solid black;}

```
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-6">
        <div class="col box">col 1</div>
        <div class="col box">col 2</div>
        <div class="col box">col 3</div>
        <div class="col box">col 4</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col box">col right</div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: As you can see [in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#nesting), nesting require another inner row, since *"In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows."*

Comment: That did it. I kept going through the examples. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you,